blender freezes regularly, it uses 100% of one of my 4 CPUs
I use blender on 3 different machines, 2 of them with 4 CPUs and one with only 1 CPU. Although the machine with one CPU is the oldest, it is the only one where I can work with blender. The machines with 4 CPUs (using linux mint and Pop_OS) show me that they use 100 +-2% of CPU, but they do nothing, I cannot stop blender, I have to kill the process.
I have no GPU, maybe that is the problem, but that is noted in my preferences, and of course in the 4 CPU machines I don't get so far that I could render something.
My old machine uses about 40% of CPU when working, so what is happening here? I use blender 4.1, but the problem started with  earlier blender versions.
Can You help?
Thanks, Siegfried
